# Array is returned as an object using resource

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-7, laravel-resource

something strange is going on.

I got an array like this:

```
=> [
     "optionalinformation" => [
       "domain" => [
         "type" => "string",
       ],
     ],
   ]
```

This array is used by a resource and if I use tinker to check this resource like this:

```
$result = App\Http\Resources\ProductResource::make(Product::find(2));

is_array($result->optionalinformation);
```

In this case the result is `true`: This is an array.

But if axios fetches the result, I am getting this:

```
"optionalinformation": {
      "domain": {
        "type": "string"
      },
```

It's no longer an array but an object. Any ideas why this is happening?

This is my api-resource:

```
 /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'                      => $this->id,
            'title'                   => $this->title,
            'optionalinformation'     => $this->optionalinformation,
        ];
    }
```

Comment: What kind of result do u expected?

Comment: Well: I'd expect an array.

Comment: plz post the example for js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bit of confusion here, mostly caused by PHP lingo.

In PHP lingo an associative array is still an array. But an associative array is actually a dictionary.

Other programming languages don't see an associative array (dictionary) as an array and as such have a different vocabulary.

Your data structure is actually a dictionary, and not a numerical indexed array.

From a JSON perspective if your data structure has non-numerical keys then it gets translated to an object.

Your confusion stems from the fact that `is_array` will return true if the variable is a zero based indexed array, when in fact it returns true for associate arrays also.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the definition. `Laravel's resource classes allow you to expressively and easily transform your models and model collections into JSON.` Check the [Resource docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#concept-overview)

If you are expecting an array in return then I suggest skip resource and pass the data directly from the controller using `->toArray()`. But then again you are using `axios` in your vuejs then I strongly recommend to stick with `json` format as an expected response.